# How to request for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS json file through Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I have a Python script that accesses Google cloud platform, I also set up the service account, I can request & save the json file through the cloud console webpage after I login my Google account, and sets the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to that json file, so the Python script can have access.

Now I want to share it with others, I have `requirements.txt` for the Python scrip to install the gcloud-api library, but I don't want to enforce others to install gcloud-sdk. And I don't want to share that json file with others. I would like to let others run the script, and if that json credential file is not found, the script will ask them to:

1. login gcloud
2. generate and save json credential, e.g., to a default directory
3. sets GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to that json file

All the step better be done without browser. Is there a way to use Python to do such thing? I did some research & googling but no luck.

I believe I can do this anyway by Python invoking `curl` or using `requests`, but just wonder if there is a simpler way to do this.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to the comments but I just want to release to others a Python script file.
I read through the service account and the work identity federation, I don‘t have infra to setup identity provider. I believe that based on my reading and the comments, if I want to use something like oauth, I need to register my script as a client on Google. I am not sure if this is feasible or considered as a good practice...

Comment: 1) Unless you are providing credentials, logins are via the browser. 2) what is **login gcloud**?. Do you mean using the CLI command **gcloud auth login**? 3) The CLI can generate and save JSON credentials. However, with the proper setup, your app can use the Application Default Credentials that the CLI stores. 4) There are two primary forms of authorization in Google Cloud Role-based and Identity-Based. Which one to use depends on details not present in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley i mean login through web browser at `cloud.google.com`. CLI can generate and save JSON, but that means you need to install the CLI tool (the Google cloud SDK), i dont want to deliver something to others that needs extra installation.

Comment: There are three types of authentication: 1) Google Accounts which requires a web browser session to authenticate. 2) Google Cloud Service Accounts. 3) Federation - look at Google Cloud Identity. There is also Workload Identity Federation but that is even more complex. 4) You either need to provide credentials to the user (a service account, OAuth Token, etc) or use OAuth via a web browser. Even headless devices require the user to launch a web browser and enter a code from the device.

Comment: 5) Your design is a security nightmare - do not provide end users with Google Cloud credentials. However, your question does not provide the level of details that can result in an informed answer. Study how authentication and authorization work in Google and Google Cloud first and then adapt your application to the cloud instead of making the cloud fit your concepts.

Comment: Following on the statement by @John Hanley, If you want to give access or share to your script within your colleague one of the best way is setting-up a service account [https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts?hl=en#what_are_service_accounts]. You can also authenticate it using Python [https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production?hl=en#auth-cloud-implicit-python], just to make sure to follow these best practices on securing a service account [https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-securing-service-accounts#impersonate-privileged].